# ¿Cómo puedo usar `cut` para mostrar un dato referente a otro?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cut

Tengo por ejemplo el `group`y quiero saber el `GID` de un grupo determinado.

```
root:x:0:
bin:x:1:
daemon:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
```

Ejemplo, de los anteriores, quiero ver el `GID` del grupo `tty`.

Si mal no recuerdo es para obtener la fila del `GID`es:

```
cut group -d ":" -f 3
```

¿Pero cómo hago la búsqueda del renglón?

Answer (score 4):

Una forma sencilla es usando `grep` y tuberías:

```
grep tty /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3
```

Con `grep tty /etc/group` obtenemos la línea dónde aparece `tty`, la salida la conectamos con el comando `cut`, en este caso la entrada no es un archivo sino la salida del comando anterior.

Comment: mil gracias. luego de la consulta logré dar con la combinación. de nuevo gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: si quisiera guardar el resultado de `grep tty /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3`en una variable, es decir que la variable adquiera el `5` que devuelve, puede ser `var = $(grep tty /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3)` ?

Comment: Si, pero sin espacios en el " =  ", es decir: `var=$(grep tty /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3)`

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza Awk para hacer las dos cosas de golpe:

```
awk -F: '$1=="tty" {print $3}' /etc/group
```

Lo que está haciendo esto es:

- `-F:` define ":" como el separador de campos
- `$1=="tty" {print $3}` indica que si el primer campo es exactamente "tty" que entonces imprima el tercer campo.

Answer (score 3):

También lo puedes hacer con (GNU) `grep` solo:

```
$ grep -oP '^tty:[^:]*:\K\d+' /etc/group
5
```

Esta expresión busca líneas que empiecen por "tty" y que vayan seguidas de un bloque entre dos puntos. Después, imprime solamente la parte numérica que lo sigue.

Si no, como que `cut` también te puede dar más de un campo, puedes hacer:

```
$ cut -d: -f 1,3 /etc/group | grep tty
tty:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Me sorprende que nadie quiera usar al buen y versátil `getent` :(

`getent` devuelve entradas de alguna de las bases de datos, y puede buscar según alguna clave. Estas bases de datos están definidas en `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Para hacer uso de `getent` con la base de datos `groups` y buscar el registro con la clave `tty`, podemos hacer lo siguiente.

```
$ getent group tty | cut -d : -f 3
5
```

El *stdout* de `getent group tty` es `tty:x:5:` y "alimenta" al *stdin* de `cut` a través del *pipeline*.

Otras versiones más ofuscadas, pero divertidas y educativas, son

```
cut -d : -f 3 <(getent group tty)
```

El cual hace uso de un *process subtitution* y crea un *named pipe* temporal que "alimenta" al comando `cut` emulando que es un archivo cuando es el resultado del comando `getent`.

```
getent group tty > >(cut -d : -f 3)
```

El cual hace uso de otro *process substitution* y crea otro *named pipe* temporal que *es alimentado* por la salida de `getent`. `getent group tty` conecta su *stdout* al *stdin* del *named pipe* creado con el *process substitution*.

Esto es para mostrar lo referente a tu pregunta sobre mostrar un dato referente a otro. Que también se podría utilizar (de forma ineficiente y forzada) un script, pero es forzar el asunto aunque también lo resuelve.

Esta forma de obtener la información de grupo, también se combina con las respuestas ya dadas anteriormente.